# Getting the current user in express.js, while using socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I'm using the express framework, and part of my web app uses socket.io to enable real-time chat. I need to get the current user's username, and create a room with him in it. The problem is I can't find a way to get the user info when socket.on('connection') is called. Here's the relevant code I have so far :

```
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');                                                                                    
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;                                                                
var mongoose = require('mongoose');                                                                                    
var session = require('express-session');                                                                              
var http = require('http');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var app = express();                                                                                                   
var server = http.createServer(app);                                                                                   
var io = require('socket.io')(server);                                                                                 

server.listen(4000);
app.use(session({secret : 'anything',                                                                                  
    saveUninitialized: true,                                                                                           
    resave: true}));                                                                                                   
app.use(passport.initialize());                                                                                        
app.use(passport.session());

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/my_db');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;                                                                                          
var UserDetail = new Schema({                                                                                          
    username: String,                                                                                                  
    password: String                                                                                                   
}, {                                                                                                                   
    collection: 'users'                                                                                                
});                                                                                                                    
var UserDetails = mongoose.model('users', UserDetail);                                                                 

app.use('/', routes);                                                                                                  
app.use('/users', users);                                                                                              

app.post('/login',                                                                                                     
        passport.authenticate('local', {                                                                               
            successRedirect: '/loginSuccess',                                                                          
            failureRedirect: '/loginFailure',                                                                          
        })                                                                                                             
        );

io.on('connection', function(socket) {                                                                                 
    console.log('socket stuff');                                                                                       
    var sessionStore = session;                                                                                        
    var sessionId    = socket.handshake.sessionId;                                                                     

    sessionStore.get(sessionId, function(err, session) {                                                               
        if(!err) {                                                                                                     
            console.log('no error');                                                                                   
            if(session.passport.user) {                                                                                
                console.log('This is the users email address %s', session.passport.user);                              
            }                                                                                                          
        }                                                                                                              
    });                                                                                                                
    socket.emit('newMessage', {content : 'Chat message content'});                                                     
});
```

The last function is where I'm having trouble. When a user requests a page, I can just find their username by req.user, but I have no idea how to do it when I don't have req. The code I have for sessions in io.on('connection') does not work at all, and just throws errors, figured I'd keep it in to show what I've tried so far.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, have you found the answer to this?

Comment: If you're using passport like the op, then passport.socketio package is an easy way to get the user passed with socket

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked a few times but the older answers I found do not work anymore. The answer lies in parsing `socket.handshake.headers.cookie` but this is hacky and will depend on the internals of `express-session`.

Anyways, this should work for now with Express 4 and socket.io 1.1:

```
var express   = require('express'),
    session   = require('express-session'),
    cookie    = require('cookie'),
    signature = require('cookie-signature');

var app    = express(), 
    store  = new session.MemoryStore(),
    secret = 'session-secret-key',
    name   = 'connect.sid';

app.use(session({
  name:   name,
  secret: secret,
  store:  store,
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));

var server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io     = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  if (socket.handshake && socket.handshake.headers && socket.handshake.headers.cookie) {
    var raw = cookie.parse(socket.handshake.headers.cookie)[name];
    if (raw) {
      // The cookie set by express-session begins with s: which indicates it
      // is a signed cookie. Remove the two characters before unsigning.
      socket.sessionId = signature.unsign(raw.slice(2), secret) || undefined;
    }
  }
  if (socket.sessionId) {
    store.get(socket.sessionId, function(err, session) {
      console.log(session);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: what does 'signature.unsign()' actually do?

Comment: It checks the session ID against the signature and returns it if the cookie has not been tampered with. The ID can be extracted without unsigning as well but that would make using signed cookies pointless. The signature is calculated from the session ID and `secret`. See https://github.com/visionmedia/node-cookie-signature for example.