# how to make redis session store available in socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, redis, socket.io

I am using node.js with socket.io and redisStore for my express-sessions. on my socket handshake, i want to read the cookie to get the session cookie, so i am able to read from and write to the session.
here is what i got so far:

in my app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var redis = require('redis');
var redisClient = redis.createClient(6379, 'localhost');

server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('listening on *:8080');
});

var io = require('./routes/index').listen(server);
var routes = require('./routes/index').router;

app.use(session({
    secret: 'my-secret-string',
    key: 'express.sid',
    cookie: { maxAge: 2628000000 },
    store: new (require('express-sessions'))({
        storage: 'redis',
        instance: redisClient,
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 6379, 
    }),
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.use('/', routes);

module.exports = app;
```

and in my index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var socketio = require('socket.io');
var io;

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    //do stuff here...
    res.render('index', { params: params });
}

var listen = function(app) {

    io = socketio.listen(app);

    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

        console.log(socket.handshake); // there is an handshake object with cookie information
                                       // which i can parse the express.sid (=sessionID) from

        socket.on('someEvent', function(args, callback) {
            //do stuff here 
            callback(err, msg);
        });
    });
    return io;  
}

module.exports = {
    listen: listen,
    router: router
}
```

Now, when the client emits "someEvent", i want to read the session ID from the session cookie and do stuff with the session data.

I followed [this](http://howtonode.org/socket-io-auth) guide, and [this](http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/), but they seem to be outdated or do not fit quite my setup. 
Had have no luck so far. Help is greatly appreciated! This is my first node.js project..

Comment: The answer I provided here shows the cookie parsing and fetching from store: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25374093/getting-the-current-user-in-express-js-while-using-socket-io/25375468#25375468 In addition you need to make the store visible to `index.js`, now it's created in `app.js` so you cannot access it in the `io.on('connection')` callback.